# Drupal 6 Rest Server = 404 from browser?

Tags: drupal, rest, post, get

New to REST Server but I think I've been through the related docs and comments yesterday and today to no avail.

I have Rest Server installed and on the "Services" admin page it is linked under "Servers" as "Rest - /services/rest". But the link returns "404 not found: could not find resource." The list of "Services" linked below all return good looking results, so I think the Services module is working well.

I've tried a variety of URLs in the browser with the same 404 result:

- /services/rest/system.connect
- /services/rest/system/connect
- /services/rest?method=system.connect
- etc.

I've also tried POST'ing to /services/rest with method variable and tried all these URLs, POSTing with an API key generated in the admin "Services" section.  Nothing but 404.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED:

I was inadvertantly using Services 2.0

If you're stuck: REST Server and JSON Server are working after installing Services 3 (requiring CTools, AutoLoad, InputStreamHelper modules).

I set up an endpoint with name/path = "rest" and I receive the expected JSON response when posting something to "/rest/system/connect.json".

Answer (score 0):

using services 2.x

**Results in XML**
POST /services/rest/service_system/connect
Content Type: text/xml

**Results in JSON**
POST /services/rest/service_system/connect.json